# Poor performance with mongo array index

Tags: arrays, mongodb, indexing

Hi I know there has been much said regarding this but I'm unable to find an answer to my specific problem. I have the following JSON document and trying to create an efficient index for the questions.questionEntry.metaTags array:

```js
{
  "questions": [
    {
      "questionEntry": {
        "id": 1,
        "info": {
          "seasonNumber": 1,
          "episodeNumber": 1,
          "episodeName": "Days Gone Bye"
        },
        "questionItem": {
          "theQuestion": "",
          "attachedElement": {
            "type": 1,
            "value": ""
          }
        },
        "options": [
          {
            "type": 1,
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "type": 1,
            "value": ""
          }
        ],
        "answer": {
          "questionId": 1,
          "answer": 1
        },
        "metaTags": [
          "Season 1",
          "Episode 1"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I then  added 5000,000 duplicate documents to my DB and an additional document with different data fields to run some tests.

I ran the following query on the unindexed collection with an execution time of 640ms: 
`db.questions1.find({"questions.questionEntry.metaTags" : "Season 1"},{'questions.$':1})._addSpecial( "$explain", 1 ).pretty()`

Then I created the following index: 
`db.questions1.createIndex( { "questions.questionEntry.metaTags" : 1 })`

Now I ran the same query but now the execution time is 9070ms...!

Here is the explain() showing 500001 documents examined!:

```js
{
        "queryPlanner" : {
                "plannerVersion" : 1,
                "namespace" : "test.questions1",
                "indexFilterSet" : false,
                "parsedQuery" : {
                        "questions.questionEntry.metaTags" : {
                                "$eq" : "Season 1"
                        }
                },
                "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "PROJECTION",
                        "transformBy" : {
                                "questions.$" : 1
                        },
                        "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "FETCH",
                                "inputStage" : {
                                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                        "keyPattern" : {
                                                "questions.questionEntry.metaTa
s" : 1
                                        },
                                        "indexName" : "questions.questionEntry.
etaTags_1",
                                        "isMultiKey" : true,
                                        "direction" : "forward",
                                        "indexBounds" : {
                                                "questions.questionEntry.metaTa
s" : [
                                                        "[\"Season 1\", \"Seaso
 1\"]"
                                                ]
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                },
                "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
        },
        "executionStats" : {
                "executionSuccess" : true,
                "nReturned" : 500001,
                "executionTimeMillis" : 11255,
                "totalKeysExamined" : 500001,
                "totalDocsExamined" : 500001,
                "executionStages" : {
                        "stage" : "PROJECTION",
                        "nReturned" : 500001,
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 10750,
                        "works" : 500002,
                        "advanced" : 500001,
                        "needTime" : 0,
                        "needFetch" : 0,
                        "saveState" : 3907,
                        "restoreState" : 3907,
                        "isEOF" : 1,
                        "invalidates" : 0,
                        "transformBy" : {
                                "questions.$" : 1
                        },
                        "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "FETCH",
                                "nReturned" : 500001,
                                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 9310,
                                "works" : 500002,
                                "advanced" : 500001,
                                "needTime" : 0,
                                "needFetch" : 0,
                                "saveState" : 3907,
                                "restoreState" : 3907,
                                "isEOF" : 1,
                                "invalidates" : 0,
                                "docsExamined" : 500001,
                                "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                                "inputStage" : {
                                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                        "nReturned" : 500001,
                                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 8970,
                                        "works" : 500001,
                                        "advanced" : 500001,
                                        "needTime" : 0,
                                        "needFetch" : 0,
                                        "saveState" : 3907,
                                        "restoreState" : 3907,
                                        "isEOF" : 1,
                                        "invalidates" : 0,
                                        "keyPattern" : {
                                                "questions.questionEntry.metaTa
s" : 1
                                        },
                                        "indexName" : "questions.questionEntry.
etaTags_1",
                                        "isMultiKey" : true,
                                        "direction" : "forward",
                                        "indexBounds" : {
                                                "questions.questionEntry.metaTa
s" : [
                                                        "[\"Season 1\", \"Seaso
 1\"]"
                                                ]
                                        },
                                        "keysExamined" : 500001,
                                        "dupsTested" : 500001,
                                        "dupsDropped" : 0,
                                        "seenInvalidated" : 0,
                                        "matchTested" : 0
                                }
                        }
                },
                "allPlansExecution" : [ ]
        },
        "serverInfo" : {
                "host" : "Voltage",
                "port" : 27017,
                "version" : "3.0.3",
                "gitVersion" : "b40106b36eecd1b4407eb1ad1af6bc60593c6105"
        }
}
```

Mongo db is not my thing and I'm struggling to understand why execution is taking longer?

What would be the best method to index the string metaTags array?

Many thanks

Comment: Please remove the `.explain()` part and rerun. Also, how much RAM does your machine have available?

Comment: Please do not post the same question twice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30656436/mongo-createindex-on-element-array-poor-performance Will vote to close that one.